# I would like to 'text-overlay' on the top of a video inside a <div> so I can resize/position them together

Tags: html, css, html5-video, overlay, nav

The idea is for mobile-view to have several videos overlayed with the nav-links. So far I tried to add one video tag in the same `li` as the home-index link so they are contained together but can't overlay them. I tried `object-fit:cover;` and `background-image:cover;` but they don't react.

Any tips on how I should approach that concept without using `position:absolute;` on the video? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I actually realized that CSS-grid is the easiest to use via grid-template-areas. I assigned them to the same area and that overlayed them beautifully.